# Códigos PHP realizam cadastro mas não fazem login

Tags: php, mysql, login

Eu possuo 6 páginas em PHP, duas delas me apresentam problemas:

- **entrada.php** (onde estão os dados de conexão do banco de dados)
- **cliente.php** (é a página de login, apenas formatação html)
- **login.php** (arquivo que confere e efetua login)
- **vip.php** (é a página restrita aos usuários cadastrados)
- **cadastro.php** (é uma página de cadastro, apenas formatação html)
- **cadastrar.php** (arquivo que confere e realiza o cadastro)

A página de conexão ***entrada.php*** está funcionando, digo isso porque o sistema de cadastro funciona perfeitamente (***cadastro.php*** e ***cadastrar.php***)

O problema está em fazer o login, antes funcionava normalmente, mas após atualizar os estilos (!) simplesmente essa parte parou de funcionar, já tentei outros códigos, mas não consegui por minha inexperiência em php, segue os problemáticos códigos (em partes):

**vip.php** - Página com a Session

```
    <?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['documentoSession']) AND !isset($_SESSION['contratoSession'])){
    header("Location: cliente.php");
    exit;
}
   ?>
```

**cliente.php** - Que faz, ou deveria fazer, o login

```
   <?php

//Conexão com o banco de dados
include "entrada.php";

// Inicia a sessão
session_start(); 

//Dados preenchidos no formulário
$documento = $_POST['documento'];
$contrato = $_POST['contrato'];

//Comparação e validação dos dados
$sql_acesso = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM iAzulDataBase WHERE Documento = '$documento' AND Contrato = '$contrato'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_acesso) == 1){

    $_SESSION['documentoSession'] = $documento;
    $_SESSION['contratoSession'] = $contrato;
    include "iAzulVIP.php";

}else{

    unset($_SESSION['documentoSession']);
    unset($_SESSION['contratoSession']);
    include "cliente.php";
}
?>
```

**cliente.php** - código do html login (por ser um código privado, parte foi retirado)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>  

<body class="metro" onLoad="setFocus()">


    <div class="total">
    <div class="pagina">
    <div class="logotipo">
    <h1><a href="#"><img src="Lion/Logotipo.png" alt="x" width="300px"></a></h1></div>
            <div class="acessorapido">
        <h2 class="text-info"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Área do Cliente</h2>
        <h4 class="text-info">Acesse aqui sua página exclusiva x</h4></div><br>

    <div class="acessorapido">
    <div class="database_center">
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <fieldset><br>

            <strong>CPF ou CNPJ:</strong><br>
            <div class="input-control text size4">
            <input type="number" name="documento" id="documento" />
            </div><br>

            <strong>Nº do Contrato:</strong><br>
            <div class="input-control text size4">
            <input type="number" name="contrato" />
            </div><br>

            <div class="alinharbutao">
            <button type="submit" class="large button info" name="login">Acessar</button>
            </div><br>

        </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div></div><!--Fim do Formulário de Cadatro-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O ficheiro login.php ? Coloque o codigo do formulário do login

Comment: esta nomeado como entrada.php

Comment: Coloque o codigo do formulário do login

Comment: Dá algum erro ? o que acontece ?

Comment: coloquei o código, não aparece nenhum erro, apenas volta para a tela de login, como deveria fazer caso o documento ou contrato (usuário e senha desse esquema) estivesse errado, mas não é esse o problema...

Comment: em cliente.php use session_start() no inicio da página, logo abaixo da tag de abertura do php. Não sei se vai ser a solução do problema, mas é uma boa prática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça ai um teste onde coloca para dar include se o login for sucesso tire o include e coloque

```
echo "
<script>
    window.location = 'iAzulVIP.php';
</script>
";
```

Veja e diga o resultado

Comment: O.o Nossa, foi o problema mais rápido que resolvi na vida, cara muito obrigado, foi show...

Comment: Resolveu então ? dessa forma ?

Comment: Só ficou a duvida do porque antes funcionava? o servidor php eu alterei de 5.4 para 5.3, para evitar alguma incompatibilidade

Comment: Resolveu, está perfeito todo o resto, inclusive o sistema de logout e se fechar o navegador ele "mata" a session

Comment: Resolveu sim, trocando o código pelo que você colocou na resposta, foi essa a solução :D

Comment: marque a resposta como certa

Comment: ainda bem boa continuação